# After changing password don't redirect my desired page in django

Tags: django

```
 path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change_done.html'),
        name='password_change_done'),

    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change.html'),
        name='password_change'),
```

Here is my two url path. After changing password the new url should be `'password_change/done/'` and should show some thing that is in template.
but when I change my password it goes to `'password_change/done/'` url but shows something that is default in django saying `password change succesful` does not show login link that is in template. How can I fix this?

here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <p class="m-auto">Your password has been set. You may go ahead and <a href="{% url 'loginuser' %}">Login in</a> now.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the correct path is that accounts/password/reset/, change it on your url and it will work

Comment: how did you find correct path?

Comment: it did not work!

Comment: what is the url that you have when you are on the change done ?

Comment: url is that you have provided but can not go to my given template.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentations where you can find the correct path for the built in auth system
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/)

in your case your urls should be changed to this

```
 path('accounts/password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change_done.html'),
        name='password_change_done'),

    path('accounts/password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change.html'),
        name='password_change'),

#you need also to add this to the urlpatterns of your project 

    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```